# Package installer dialog dismissible?

Tags: android, kotlin, packageinstaller

I am working so some demo app store. This app can detect deep link and install app from link. Before installing app user gets dialog (at least on Android 11 and 12) where he/she can click on Install or Cancel. Dialog is opened by `PackageInstaller`. I am using `BroadcastReceiver` to receive installation status (for example `PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION`). When user clicks on cancel or install or some error happens I receive a status.

But user can click outside of dialog. Dialog is smilingly dismissed and no status is reported back.

Is there way to get status? Or to make dialog non dismissible?

EDIT: dialog is create by `PackageInstaller` and I don’t have control it's properties.

Comment: Try this with your dialog  //  .setCancelable(false)

Comment: I don’t have control over dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly - no, but you can:

1. Track `onResume` event to detect when it's closed (it requires some filtering to avoid false detection);
2. Wrap it into some proxy activity and use `startActivityForResult`/`onActivityResult` to start that `EXTRA_INTENT` from `STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION`. `resultCode` is always `0`, but you'll have an closing event at least.